# Calculate the leave net entitlement difference between two days

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

There are two queries i am fetching one which gives todays absence balance 
and another which will will give yesterdays absence balance

Todays Net entitlement :

```
query 1 :


select e.emp_no,
a.absence_code,
a.net_entitlement
from emp_details e,
absence_tab_history a
where a.person_id=e.person_id
and a.history_date=trunc(sysdate);
```

Yesterday's net entitlemet :

```
query 2 :

select e.emp_no,
a.absence_code,
a.net_entitlement
from emp_details e,
absence_tab_history a
where a.person_id=e.person_id
and a.history_date=trunc(sysdate)-1;
```

now query 1 will fetch columns for todays net entitlement such as

```
emp no. Absence code        net entitlement

1        Sick Leave             9
2        Privilege Leave        5
3        Sick Leave             5
```

now query 2 will fetch columns for yesterdays  net entiltement of employees

```
emp no. Absence code        net entitlement

1        Sick Leave             10
2        Privilege Leave        5
3        Sick Leave             6
```

This means that emp no. 1 and 2's net entitlement have changed and both of them have taken 1 leave  each. Now i want to create a query which captures the same ie. only emp 1 and 2 
That is if teh net entitlement has changed  then displays the changed rows only.
Minus is not working for this and is taking too much time to execute. Kindly help

Comment: Why can't you just show today's row?  If the value hasn't changed, then yesterday's value and today's values are the same.

Comment: have edited the question. i only need the changed rows.... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    with present_day 
as
(
select 1 as emp_id,'Sick Leave' as code , 9 as net_entitlement from dual
union
select 2 as emp_id,'Privilege Leave' as code , 5 as net_entitlement from dual
union
select 3 as emp_id,'Sick Leave' as code , 5 as net_entitlement from dual
),
yester_day
as
(
select 1 as emp_id,'Sick Leave' as code , 10 as net_entitlement from dual
union
select 2 as emp_id,'Privilege Leave' as code , 5 as net_entitlement from dual
union
select 3 as emp_id,'Sick Leave' as code , 6 as net_entitlement from dual
)

select a.emp_id,a.code,a.net_entitlement,decode(a.net_entitlement-b.net_entitlement,0,'UNCHG','CHNG')
from present_day a,yester_day b
where a.emp_id=b.emp_id and a.code=b.code
and decode(a.net_entitlement-b.net_entitlement,0,'UNCHG','CHNG')='CHNG'
```

Try the above code and let me know

Comment: That's what I have done. May be a bit differently.  Your requirement is bit vague.

Comment: @user3809240 Let me know if it's fine now. Please consider accepting the answer is it serves the purpose

Comment: Hi @ASFAKUL... the net_enttitement is coming 0 still the decode is returing 'CHNG' using this query

Comment: When I tested it i got emp Id 1 and 3

Comment: What if present day has a new record and yesterday does not have it ? This query will not fetch those records ? @asfakul

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58630/discussion-between-user3809240-and-asfakul-islam).

Answer (score 0):

You need to bring the data together in the tables to do the comparison.  Here is one method:

```
select e.emp_no, coalesce(a.absence_code, ath.absence_code) as absence_code,
       a.net_entitlement, ath.net_entitlement
from emp_details e left join
     absence_tab_history ath
     on ath.person_id = e.person_id and
        ath.history_date = trunc(sysdate) - 1 left join
     absence_tab a
     on a.person_id = e.person_id
where a.person_id is null or
      ath.person_id is null or
      ath.net_entitlement <> a.net_entitlement;
```

The first two conditions in the `where` clause are for new employees who appear and for former employees who leave.

Comment: By leave i meant being absent not leaving teh firm :) @gordon

Comment: @user3809240 . . . What I meant is that new employees will appear one day and not be in the history.  Similarly, former employees will disappear one day, and be in the history but not the current data.